# Phrases describing what an option does and that starts with a verb: "s" at the end of the verb or not?

Tags: grammar

For phrases describing what an option does and that starts with a verb, should an "s" be added at the end of the verb or not?

Example:

"Detect if spaces or other characters are present in the phrase"

... or:

"Detects if spaces or other characters are present in the phrase"

Comment: I would prefer the one with -s but either would be comprehensible.

Comment: Thank you @mdewey